# Find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the operator A

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the operator $A = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{2d}{xdx}$
this question is more about mathematics, but it relates to physics

$A\Psi = \lambda\Psi$

$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + \frac{2d\Psi}{xdx} - \lambda\Psi = 0$

Then I multiply on $x^2$

$x^2\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + 2x\frac{d\Psi}{dx} - x^2\lambda\Psi = 0$

next, I take $\Psi = x^k$ and get something similar to the Euler equation, but it seems to me it is not. Can you tell me what method to use here to solve the equation

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + 2x\frac{d\Psi}{dx} - x^2\lambda\Psi = 0$$
$$x\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + 2\frac{d\Psi}{dx} - x\lambda\Psi = 0$$
$$(x\Psi)'' - x\lambda\Psi = 0$$
$$y'' - \lambda y = 0$$
Where $y=x\Psi$. You can easily solve this linear DE with constant coefficients.